# PHP Multi-dimensional Array Reorganization

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a database and a table and am populating the table with an HTML form, and displaying ALL of the results of the entire table and all rows. How do I go through a while loop and reorganize the entire database table by cells instead of rows.  For example:

```
database table row1: c1 = dataA, c2 = dataB, c3 = dataC;
database table row2: c1 = dataD, c2 = dataE, c3 = dataF;
```

Instead I wish to store all the cells in their own array:

```
arrayC1 = [dataA, dataD];
arrayC2 = [dataB, dataE];
arrayC3 = [dataC, dataF];
```

As long as I have all the the like items in their own array, I will be able to display them however I want.

Comment: Please show us what code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the column structure will buy you anything, but if you have `$rows`:

**PHP >= 5.5.0** required, or use [PHP implementation of `array_column`](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php):

```
foreach(array_keys(reset($rows)) as $key) {
    $columns[$key] = array_column($rows, $key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution. If you have a lot of data `$rows` can be fetched one by one or in chunks from database and it will be work.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  foreach($row as $key => $val) {
    $result[$key][] = $val;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some context to you answer (e.g. why this is an answer).